# Collect Coefficients MPolynomial_libsingular

Tags: python, sage

I want to get the symbolic coefficients of a polynomial `p` in `GF(2^n)[X0, ..., X{N-1}]` translated to `GF(2)[t]`.

For example for `n = 2` and `p = X0*X1 = (x_00+x_01*t)*(x_10+x_11*t) = (x_00*x_10+x_01*x_11) + (x_01*x_11+x_01*x_10 + x_00*x_11)*t`, the method should give `[(x_00*x_10 + x_01*x_11), (x_01*x_11 + x_01*x_10 + x_00*x_11)]`.

In the code below my problem is when I want collect the coefficients of `t`. How can I collect these coefficients in an **efficient way**?

```
sage: q = 2
sage: N = 2
sage: k.<t> = GF(2^q)
sage: Xi = []
sage: xij = []
sage: for i in range(N):
....:     Xi.append(var('X' + str(i)))
....:     for j in range(q):
....:         xij.append(var('x' + str(i) + '' + str(j)))
sage: Xi.append(t)
sage: P = PolynomialRing(k, names=Xi)
sage: R = PolynomialRing(k, names=xij)
sage: S = PolynomialRing(R, 't')
sage: p = P.random_element(degree=2)
sage: subsvar = [sum((t^i*R.gen(i+q*j) for i in range(q))) for j in range(N)]
sage: subsvar.append(t)
sage: p =  p(subsvar)
sage: p
(t + 1)*x00*x10 + x01*x10 + x00*x11 + (t)*x01*x11 + (t)*x10 + (t + 1)*x11 + (t + 1)
```

Comment: I'm trying cast using SR but that is very very slow ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. For reference, I am using Sage 6.3.

Setup, with an underscore to distinguish between
eg `x1_11` and `x11_1`, for larger q and nvars.

```
q = 2
nvars = 2
k.<t> = GF(2^q)
Xi = []
xij = []
for i in range(nvars):
    Xi.append(var('X'+str(i)))
    for j in range(q):
        xij.append(var('x'+str(i)+'_'+str(j)))
P = PolynomialRing(k,names=Xi)
R = PolynomialRing(k,names=xij)
S = PolynomialRing(R,'t')
subsvar = [sum((t^i*R.gen(i+q*j) for i in range(q))) for j in range(nvars)]
```

Transform a polynomial from the ring `P` into a polynomial
in `t` with coefficients in `R`:

```
p = P('X0*X1')
pp = sum(b*S(a.polynomial()) for (a,b) in p(subsvar))
pp
```

The output is naturally collected in powers of `t`.

```
(x0_1*x1_0 + x0_0*x1_1 + x0_1*x1_1)*t + x0_0*x1_0 + x0_1*x1_1
```

Timing on your example `X0*X1`:

```
sage: timeit('pp = sum(b*S(a.polynomial()) for (a,b) in p(subsvar))')
625 loops, best of 3: 469 µs per loop
```